# how to upload file to the server in the background in Dart Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using multipart/form-data to upload files to the server using POST API in my application (using [dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) package). The problem is application must upload files in the background (even when the user quits the application). How can I achieve this? Will appreciate every response!

This is how I'm uploading file to the server

```
Future<bool> upload(File file) async {
    bool isSuccessfull = false;
    var dio = Dio();
    dio.options.baseUrl = "$baseUrl";
    dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(
        requestBody: true,
        request: true,
        responseBody: true));

    try {
      FormData formData = FormData.from({
        "iframeKey": "foofoo",
        "apikey": "foo",
        "secret": "foo",
        "fields": [
          {"key": "first_name", "value": "videoupload"},
          {"key": "larst_name", "value": "videoupload"},
          {"key": "test", "value": "videoupload"},
          {"key": "checkboxtest", "value": "true"},
          {"key": "email_address", "value": "somebody@gmail.com"}
        ],
        "file": [
          new UploadFileInfo(new File(file.path), basename(file.path)),          
        ],
      });

      Response response;
      response = await dio.post("/submit",
          data: formData,
          onSendProgress: showDownloadProgress,
          options: new Options(
            connectTimeout: 100000,
            receiveTimeout: 100000,
            contentType: ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
          ));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        isSuccessfull = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
       print(e.message);
    }
    return isSuccessfull;
  }
```

Comment: I have the same question.  For now an Android-only solution would be OK.  Also my situation does not require it to work for Terminated status, but the upload must proceed even if the app is in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader).

> This plugin is based on WorkManager in Android and
>   NSURLSessionUploadTask in iOS to run upload task in background mode.